# Vim sourcing .vim files after .vimrc

Tags: linux, vim, vi, vim-plugin

Here is the snapshot for:`scriptname`

```
  1: /etc/vimrc
  2: /usr/share/vim/vim72/syntax/syntax.vim
  3: /usr/share/vim/vim72/syntax/synload.vim
  4: /usr/share/vim/vim72/syntax/syncolor.vim
  5: /usr/share/vim/vim72/filetype.vim
  6: /usr/share/vim/vim72/ftplugin.vim
  7: /home/xxxxx/.vimrc
  8: /usr/share/vim/vim72/syntax/nosyntax.vim
  9: /usr/share/vim/vim72/indent.vim
 10: /usr/share/vim/vim72/colors/desert.vim
 11: /usr/share/vim/vim72/indoff.vim
 12: /usr/share/vim/vim72/ftplugof.vim
 13: /usr/share/vim/vim72/plugin/filetype.vim
 14: /usr/share/vim/vim72/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
 15: /usr/share/vim/vim72/plugin/gzip.vim
 16: /usr/share/vim/vim72/plugin/matchparen.vim
 17: /usr/share/vim/vim72/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
 18: /usr/share/vim/vim72/plugin/rrhelper.vim
 19: /usr/share/vim/vim72/plugin/spellfile.vim
 20: /usr/share/vim/vim72/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
 21: /usr/share/vim/vim72/plugin/tohtml.vim
 22: /usr/share/vim/vim72/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
 23: /usr/share/vim/vim72/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
 24: /usr/share/vim/vim72/syntax/cpp.vim
 25: /usr/share/vim/vim72/syntax/c.vim
 26: /home/xxxxx/.vim/after/syntax/cpp.vim
```

On 7, my vimrc is being sourced and after that couple of .vim files are being sourced.

**How do I stop these default sourcing of .vim files?**

Comment: Those are files that're sourced because of commands in your `~/.vimrc` — `syntax on`, `filetype plugin indent on` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

**Use The Noplugin Option when starting Vim**

Please look at the help file, `:help starting`.  BTW, the `:help initialization` section is a good read too.

The section on `--noplugin` describes the resulting options behavior:

```
--noplugin  Skip loading plugins.  Resets the 'loadplugins' option.

Note that the |-u| argument may also disable loading plugins:
    argument   load: vimrc files  plugins  defaults.vim ~
   (nothing)                 yes    yes   yes
    -u NONE                  no     no    no
    -u DEFAULTS              no     no    yes
    -u NORC                  no     yes   no
    --noplugin               yes    no    yes
```

Thus, Starting vim with this option will execute your vimrc, but not source plugins (though you will get defaults...):

`vim --noplugin`

As phd had indicated, your settings in your ~/.vimrc file are also responsible for the *.vim files being sourced as well (e.g. filetype settings, indentation, colorscheme).

When I execute the ex command (Vim 8.2 on Windows 10), `:scriptname`, I get:

`1: ~\_vimrc`
`2: C:\Program Files\Vim\vim82\vim82\filetype.vim`
`3: C:\Program Files\Vim\vim82\vim82\ftplugin.vim`
`4: C:\Program Files\Vim\vim82\vim82\indent.vim`
`5: C:\Program Files\Vim\vim82\vim82\syntax\syntax.vim`
`6: C:\Program Files\Vim\vim82\vim82\syntax\synload.vim`
`7: C:\Program Files\Vim\vim82\vim82\syntax\syncolor.vim`
`8: C:\Program Files\Vim\vim82\vim82\colors\murphy.vim`
`9: C:\Program Files\Vim\vim82\vim82\ftplugin\help.vim`
`10: C:\Program Files\Vim\vim82\vim82\syntax\help.vim`
`Press ENTER or type command to continue`

---

**Vim Verbose Logging Can Provide a Detailed Perspective on Plug-in Sourcing**

When starting Vim, you can use the verbose option with the verbosefile set, you can view the initialization process in as detailed a manner as you would like.

the `:help -V` entry:

```
    -V[N]           Verbose.  Sets the 'verbose' option to [N] (default: 10).                                                                                                                     
Messages will be given for each file that is ":source"d and                                                                                                                   
for reading or writing a viminfo file.  Can be used to find                                                                                                                   
out what is happening upon startup and exit.                                                                                                                                  
Example:                                                                                                                                                                              
vim -V8 foobar
```

I started my vim session with `vim --noplugin -V6vim_logging6.txt` (here N can be 1 to 10 (10 being the most logging)).  Also, I set the logging file, verbosefile, to "logging6.txt".

For our purposes of viewing the sourcing, I scrape the log file with this ex command to view just the sourcing:

```
:v/^line \d\+/d
```

I can then view the sequential sourcing only from the log file:

```
  1 line 28: sourcing "/usr/local/share/vim/vim82/filetype.vim"
  2 line 28: sourcing "/usr/local/share/vim/vim82/ftplugin.vim"
  3 line 29: sourcing "/usr/local/share/vim/vim82/filetype.vim"
  4 line 29: sourcing "/usr/local/share/vim/vim82/ftplugin.vim"
  5 line 29: sourcing "/usr/local/share/vim/vim82/indent.vim"
  6 line 30: sourcing "/usr/local/share/vim/vim82/syntax/syntax.vim"
  7 line 19: sourcing "/usr/local/share/vim/vim82/syntax/synload.vim"
  8 line 21: sourcing "/usr/local/share/vim/vim82/syntax/syncolor.vim"
  9 line 66: sourcing "/usr/local/share/vim/vim82/colors/murphy.vim"
 10 line 7: sourcing "/usr/local/share/vim/vim82/syntax/syncolor.vim"
 11 line 8: sourcing "/usr/local/share/vim/vim82/syntax/syncolor.vim"
 12 line 10: sourcing "/usr/local/share/vim/vim82/syntax/syncolor.vim"
 13 line 119: sourcing "/home/pbacon/.vimrc.plug"
 14 line 1: sourcing "/home/pbacon/.vim/autoload/plug.vim"
 15 line 14: sourcing "/usr/local/share/vim/vim82/ftoff.vim"
 16 line 83: sourcing "/usr/local/share/vim/vim82/filetype.vim"
 17 line 83: sourcing "/usr/local/share/vim/vim82/ftplugin.vim"
 18 line 83: sourcing "/usr/local/share/vim/vim82/indent.vim"
```

Comment: A small clarification, is the order of sourcing top to bottom or bottom to up?
For my scriptname, `/home/xxxxx/.vim/after/syntax/cpp.vim` , this one is sourced at last, right?

Comment: Hi @am_an, the order is top to buttom (sequentially following the numeric order returned).